# How to query nested properties of a Hashtable?

Tags: powershell

Imagine you have a `Hashtable` such as this:

```
$ht = @{
    Foo = @{
        Bar = "Baz"
        Qux = "Quux"
    }
    Quuz = @{
        Bar = "Corge"
        Qux = "Grault"
    }
}
```

Imagine that you want to get an array of each of the `Hashtable`'s `Bar` property. How would you go about this? Is this possible without iterating?

This is what I came up with:

```
$arr = @()

foreach ($i in $ht.GetEnumerator()) {
    foreach ($n in $i.Name) {
        $arr += $ht.$n.Bar
    }
}
```

```
PS C:> echo $arr
Corge
Baz
```

Really, though, it seems to me it should be simpler. Perhaps using `PSCustomObject` & `Select-Object`? I'm open to any solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell (since version 3.0) supports *member enumeration*, allowing us to simplify your loop to the following statment:

```
$arr = $ht.Values.Bar
```

Since the collection stored in `Hashtable.Values` has no `Bar` property, PowerShell enumerates it and attempts to resolve the member reference against the individual items, much like if you had done:

```
$ht.Values |ForEach-Object { $_.Bar } 
# or
$ht.Values |ForEach-Object Bar 
# or
$ht.Values |Select -Expand Bar
```

Comment: Incredible. Spent hours on googling this today, but didn't know what to search for. Thanks.

Comment: @iTiamo Hopefully you learned something else on the journey at least ^_^ now you know

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

---

```
$myDict = @{
    key1 = @{   key98 = "Hello"
                key99 = "Goodbye" } 
    key2 = 'value2' }
```

---

```
$myDict.key1

Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
key99                          Goodbye                                         
key98                          Hello                                           

PS E:\> $myDict.key2
value2

PS E:\> $myDict.key1.key98
Hello

PS E:\> $myDict.key1.key99
Goodbye
```

Comment: Please avoid placing signatures and introducing spam by this means, otherwise I will report it to a moderator.